# GitLab Pipline Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed

Tags: linux, docker, amazon-web-services, gitlab

I have the following problem with TEST fail with the following error message daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init
issue initializing the container process, which is preventing the Docker container from starting correctly.

```
  > Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime
    > create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process:
    > error during container init: error mounting
    > "/builds/data-test/platform_1/Assets/config/autoload/local.php.docker"
    > to rootfs at "/storage/Assets/config/autoload/local.php": mount
    > /builds/test/platform_1/Assets/config/autoload/local.php.docker:/storage/Assets/config/autoload/local.php
    > (via /proc/self/fd/6), flags: 0x5000: not a directory: unknown: Are
    > you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if
    > the specified host path exists and is the expected type
    > 
    > Uploading artifacts for failed job
    >

> WARNING: junit/*.xml: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path
> is relative to the working directory
> (/builds/test/platform_1/Assets)
```

what is the causes of this issue , any help would be appriciated .

Comment: I'm in the same boat.  Self hosted GitLab SaaS with a couple servers for gitlab-runner.  These hosts use docker as its executor.  The job passes with GitLab.com' runners however :s https://gitlab.com/winny/dind-test/-/pipelines/803157586